# Remove EC2 default security group

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, firewall

I set up a new region in EC2 and created a VPC network as well.  The previous region was created by an offshore company and in the setup, the only security groups that I can see are from VPC.  Security groups don't have a selection of EC2 and VPC as I'm only seeing one default.

In the second region, I see two defaults and a dropdown that lets me select/create security groups in both EC2 and VPC.

I can't seem to figure out how to remove the default security group in EC2.  It says `The security group 'default' is reserved` Somehow this offshore team was able to do it in the other region.  I tried from CLI and got the same error message

Answer (score 4):

You cannot delete that Security Group.

The reason for the difference between your two Regions is that one has been configured for both **EC2** and **VPC** (most probably the US-East-1 Region) and the other is only configured for "VPC". The available options can be viewed in the top-right corner of your EC2 Dashboard page under "Account Attributes / Supported Platforms".

**VPC** refers to Virtual Private Cloud, which allows you to configure your own private network configurations. It is the default now for all Regions.

**EC2** (commonly known as EC2-Classic) pre-dates VPC and uses a shared network space for all AWS customers. It has been progressively phased-out.

So, it would appear that your "previous region" has only VPC, while your "second region" (probably US-East-1) has both. The Default Security Group that you are trying to delete is part of EC2-Classic, and you cannot delete it. It isn't in your "previous region" because that region is not enabled for EC2-Classic.

Documentation on EC2-Classic vs EC2-VPC: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-platforms.html